# How to change placeholder text for search box in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-admin

I have enterprise edition of react-admin. I am using Search component from ra-search. Now I would like to change placeholder text in search text input. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can override 'ra.action.search' in your localisation files, but it will change the default placeholder for all 'SearchInput's in your application.

Otherwise, you must copy/paste their code from /node_modules/@react-admin/ra-search/src/Search.tsx in a file of your own, then change the "SearchInput" in the return by adding the "placeholder" props of your choice.

```
<SearchInput
    ...
    placeholder={translate('my.custom.placeholder.localization.key')}
  />
```